# pandas python replace column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose that I have a data frame with a column `a: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...`. How can I replace the values so that every number is 1 less (new a is `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`). Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just += 1:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5

In [13]: df['a'] += 1

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   a
0  2
1  3
2  4
3  5
4  6
```

Comment: FYI, should be `-1`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
>>> data['col_name']=data['col_name'].apply(lambda row:row-1)
```

You can add any other operation or functionality as well in this manner